# Javapoet - TypeName - HashMap<String, HashMap<String, List<String>>> generation?

Tags: javapoet

I'm studying Javapoet as candidate for some protocol model objects auto-generation. Grat API!

question:
Can I generate field of complicated type like:

`TypeName myType = HashMap<String, HashMap<String, List<String>>>;`
?

For example, if I want to get simpler TypeName: "HashMap<
String, String>" -
I can easily achieve it through:

ParameterizedTypeName.get(Map.class, String.class, String.class);

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```html
import java.util.ArrayList ;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class EX1 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

 HashMap<String,HashMap<String,List>>outerhashmap=new HashMap<>();
 HashMap<String,List>innerhashmap=new HashMap<>();
 List l=new ArrayList();
 l.add("shine");
 l.add("unicorn");
 l.add("twister");
 l.add("twister");
 List l1=new ArrayList();
 l1.add("passon");
 l1.add("splender");
 l1.add("karizma");
 
 innerhashmap.put("HONDA", l);
 innerhashmap.put("HERO", l1);
 
 outerhashmap.put("BIKE", innerhashmap);
 
 for(HashMap.Entry<String, HashMap<String,List>>entry:outerhashmap.entrySet()){
  String keys=entry.getKey();
  HashMap<String, List> values=entry.getValue();
  System.out.println(keys+"======="+values);
 }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: index 6 for '$T' not in range (received 5 arguments)

thus,you cant generate some fie

Answer (score 0):

We can use `TypeMirror`, which will work no matter how compicated the parameterized type is.

1. Create a sample method containing the required type as the return type.

   ```
   Map<String, List<String>> foo() {}
   ```
2. Then, *mirror* the return type using java reflections as follows:

   ```
   TypeName complexParameterizedType = ParameterizedTypeName.get(TestClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("foo").getGenericReturnType());
   MethodSpec meth = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("targetMethod").returns(complexParameterizedType).build();
   ```